# play multiple audio files in android

Tags: android

i can play a audio file frm raw folder by this way below. bt how to play multiple audio files in a directory or as in a playlist.Thankyou

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

int resourceId = R.raw.a;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create( this, resourceId );
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp )
        {
            mp.release();
        }
    } );
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple? Multiple songs at once? In a sequence? Your question should be specific and demonstrate what you've attempted so far so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple songs?

Comment: in a sequence so that I can play it as in playlist later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you are asking about playing all the mp3 file in the directory**
[you can get code to play the audio](https://github.com/DineshIT/IT.git) Try this code,i think it will help you.

It work well for me.It doesnot need any changes in manifest.xml file, you just use the MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml file to play the audio stored in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

try SoundPool,its a better method of dealing with multiple audio files at the same time.

Heres the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Heres the example:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-soundpool-example

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try SoundPool for playing multiple audio files at same time.

You can find the documentation of SoundPool here :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

I hope it will help you.