# Playing multiple audios simultaneously with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, spinner, android-mediaplayer

I got a problem with playing two `MediaPlayers` simultaneously.

In my code I made a `spinner` to let the user to choose his first song and then the second song, at the moment that the user chooses the first song it starts to play and when the user choose the second song it will play with the first one.

But the problem is that, when the user chse the second song it stops the first one...

**What can I do to fix it?**

Ty!

The code:

```
public void setSpinner() {
    Spinner spine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.song, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spine.setAdapter(adapter);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
    spine.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String st = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (st.equals("First Song")) {
                setMedia1(mp1);
                mp1.start();
            }
            if (st.equals("Second Song")) {
                setMedia2(mp1);
                mp1.start();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
public void setMedia1(MediaPlayer mp2) {

    Bundle b1=getIntent().getExtras();
    float s = b1.getFloat("speed");
    Bundle b2=getIntent().getExtras();
    float v = b2.getFloat("volume");

    try {
        String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("song1");
        final Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(s1);
        mp2.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri1);
        mp2.prepare();
        mp2.setVolume(v,v);
        mp2.setPlaybackParams(mp2.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(s));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
public void setMedia2(MediaPlayer mp2) {

    Bundle b3 = getIntent().getExtras();
    float sp1 = b3.getFloat("speed1");
    Bundle b4 = getIntent().getExtras();
    float vo1 = b4.getFloat("volume1");

    try {
        String s2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("song3");
        final Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(s2);
        mp2.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri2);
        mp2.prepare();
        mp2.setVolume(vo1, vo1);
        mp2.setPlaybackParams(mp2.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(sp1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a single `MediaPlayer` instance. Have you tried creating two `MediaPlayer`s?

Comment: I am using 2 mediaplayers...

Comment: Not in this code, you are not. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

try SoundPool,its a better method of dealing with multiple audio files at the same time.

Heres the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Heres the example:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-soundpool-example

Hope this helps

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730023/6891563)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.
As I kno soundpool is for short audios it's true?

Comment: Yes it is for short audios

Comment: I need something that will deal with long audios too...
Do you know some way  that can help me with that?

Comment: I will search and tell you, if i find something

Comment: Hi, you got any idea?

Comment: You want play two audio simultaneously, I don't think it's possible with the stock Music player. You can install a third party music player. Try forking some player app. and make them run two audio at once.

Comment: There are plenty of open source sdk, you should try and pick one that you find easy to install and consider space consuming.

Comment: Ok, thank you I going to try that, I will update you if it'll work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two `MediaPlayer` instances. Change your `setSpinner` method to do something like:

```
public void setSpinner() {
    Spinner spine = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.song, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spine.setAdapter(adapter);
    // You were only creating a single MediaPlayer instance in your version...
    final MediaPlayer mpA = new MediaPlayer();
    final MediaPlayer mpB = new MediaPlayer();
    spine.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String st = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (st.equals("First Song")) {
                // Use mpA for the first song
                setMedia1(mpA);
                mpA.start();
            }
            else if (st.equals("Second Song")) {
                // Use mpB for the second song
                setMedia2(mpB);
                mpB.start();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

I do not know if that will get the exact behavior you are looking for, but it stands a better chance at playing two songs simultaneously than using a single `MediaPlayer` instance.

Comment: I'm going to try that, ty!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to play them simultaneously without the spinner?
Because I've tried a lot of ways to do that but every single time just one mediaplayer works...

Comment: The spinner should have no bearing on the situation. If it works with the spinner, it should work without. There are a variety of things it may depend on, but it should work. I have done it albeit on custom hardware intended to play media.

Comment: @mike23 Any luck?